What would the sky look like on a planet under a green sun?
Basically what the title says. I know green stars are completely impossible, but this is a fantasy world with completely different laws of physics, so on a planet with a green sun, what color do you think the sky would look like?

If the laws of physics are completely different in your fantasy world how exactly do you expect us to be able to answer this question?

@sphennings just because the light source is not following the rules of blackbody radiation does not automatically negate how reighley scattering works.

Agree with Nosajimiki - it might not actually be a specific fantasy question (and might merit a close for vagueness) but it's perfectly fine to ask how a sky would look under a powerful green light source, at least best I can tell.

The peak output spectrum of the sun is in fact greenish ~500nm, not sure how you'd filter out other sections to get a green visible spectrum though.

@Ash That question has been asked before on WB.SE with answers generally requiring some filtering process that cuts out the red wavelengths that are a natural part of blackbody radiation... but given this questions tags, I believe it is enough to simply say: it's green because... magic!

I voted to close. you can pick one of the three: Ask a question about magic disregarding science, ask about science alone, or make up a goddamnly consistent magical system that mix science so we can work on. This question does neither.

@MindwinRememberMonica I 100% disagree. Good worldbuilding must consider the scientific consequences of magic.  When a mage casts fireball, don't we still expect the fires it leaves behind to follow the rules of chemistry? When a Jedi telekinetically throws a person across the room, don't we still expect that person to encounter Newton's laws of motion when they hit the wall?  Yes, the OP COULD make the sun green and the sky purple, but it is more immersive to confine magic to that which is magic itself, and determine the consequences of that magic on the world via natural laws.

even if this is not how you would handle magic in your setting, it is in no way off topic for another worldbuilder to choose where they want to draw thier lines between magic and reality.

@Nosajimiki OP gets to decide the rules of their world. When they mirror our own and when they do something different. However they need to specify what the rules are for us to answer their question. For all we know the different physics impact how light works in a meaningful way. Or perhaps they are deliberately handwaving and the sun is green just because thats how things work in their world. However we should not assume what the OPs intent is from a question needing clarification. We should request clarification and put the question on hold until it is edited to be free from issues.

Remember that Stack Overflow is very strict about the way questions are asked as part of its core philosophy. That philosophy also includes an expectation that users only answer well asked questions.

@Nosajimiki your first sentence claim is invalid. You can have good worldbuilding while flipping the bird to physics. The creator only needs good internal consistency. Ask Terry Pratchett about his flat world on a space elephants and turtles, if you don't believe me. Once you add magic, not even the sky is the limit.

@MindwinRememberMonica Just because discworld has linear gravity instead of circular gravity, and clear violations of biological integrity, did nothing to stop Lupine from falling to his death all the same.  My point is that just because a thing can be answered by magic in a setting does not mean that it will be or that readers will automatically disregard the expectation for the expected.

@sphennings Oh, I think I am seeing what yall are seeing now.  The OP says "I know green stars are completely impossible, but this is a fantasy world" which I took as a clear indication of wanting to magic the sun green which is fine, but when he continued to say "completely different laws of physics", that is very different than just saying blackbody radiation works differently.  If the laws of physics are completely different, then we need to know how they are different. I've retracted my reopen vote.

Midday skies will be somewhere between Green and Blue
The Rayleigh effect acts more-or-less like a blue filter. Technically speaking, air scatters light of different wavelengths differently. A lot more short wave light (blue) scatters than long wave light (red); so, we only see the red light coming from the angle of the sun itself, but some of the blue light scatters so we can see it in every direction making the sky look blue.  So this question can be simplified by asking what color is a green light when shined through such a filter.
This leads us to have to question, just how green your star is. Green is the color of light when it has middle wavelengths, but lacking in long or short wavelengths.  So, if you sun is very green, it means there is no red or blue light to scatter; so, your sky, and literally everything else will be green: You are, for all practical purposes, colorblind.
However, if your sun emits mostly green light but has some red and blue light, then Rayleigh scattering will still scatter most of the blue, some green, and little red, resulting in a sky color shifted to be more blue than the green sunlight, but less blue than our own sky. Depending on how purely green you star is, this could be a slightly-blue green like Aquamarine, a balanced blue green like Cyan, or a slightly-green blue like Cerulean.

Sunsets will be somewhere between Green and Red
That said, the Rayleigh effect is a little more complex than a simple filter.  When light has to pass through a enough air like it does at sunrise or sunset, most of the blue and green light gets absorbed by the air and the red light scatters enough make the sky look red.  When this happens to a green light, the absence of red to scatter will make the sky look darker with only trace amounts of green shining through since most of your star's light will just be absorbed by the air.


What I like most about this answer is that it reflects the behavior of our sky chart, simply replacing the red end of the spectrum with green and holding onto science otherwise.

just here for fun and trying to understand the answer: doesn't the Rayleigh effect filter out blue light? For example, on earth when we look toward the sun it is shifted more yellow or red depending on the thickness of atmosphere (on horizon could look red)

@villaa Air scatters light of different wavelengths differently; so, it is not technically a "filter" in the strictest since.  When the sun is overhead, only the blue light scatters but the red light goes straight; so, we only see the red light coming from the angle of the sun itself, but some of the blue light scatters so we can see it in every direction.  We can see red skies at dusk because the thicker air is enough to scatter the red light and absorb the blue light.

Ok, but does this match up with this sentence in the answer (emphasis mine): "...light that passes through it. Basically it removes most of the red light, some of the green light, and very little of the blue light."

@villaa no, I was using a filter as an analogy, because the spectral effects are basically the same.  That said, I've updated my answer to be more clear about how the Rayleigh effect specifically works.
